# When a matrix constructed of real and imaginary parts of a complex matrix is nonsingular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers

I have a $2n \times n$ matrix $H$ with complex elements $c_{i,j}$, where $i$ runs from $1$ to $2n$ and $j$ runs from $1$ to $n$. Next I construct a $2n\times 2n$ real matrix
$$A=\left[\mathrm{Re}\{H\} \ \mathrm{Im}\{H\} \right].$$

The question is what should I assume about $H$ to ensure that $A$ is nonsingular?

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea. Suppose $A$ is singular. Then there exists $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\lambda\ne 0$, such that $\lambda^\top A = 0$. We have $$\lambda^\top A = \lambda^\top \begin{bmatrix}\mathrm{Re}\{H\} & \mathrm{Im}\{H\}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\lambda^\top\mathrm{Re}\{H\} & \lambda^\top\mathrm{Im}\{H\}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\mathrm{Re}\{\lambda^\top H\} & \mathrm{Im}\{\lambda^\top H\}\end{bmatrix}=0.$$  That is possible if and only if $\lambda^\top H = 0$. Recall that $\lambda$ is a vector of reals and $H$ is a matrix of complex values.

Let $v^{(k)}\in \mathbb{C}^{2n}$ be the $k$-th column of $H$. Let the $i$-th element be $v^{(k)}_i = L^{(k)}_i \exp(\mathrm{i}\phi^{(k)}_i)$, where $L$ and $\phi$ are the magnitude and the phase, respectively, reals. $\lambda^\top H = 0$ implies that $\lambda^\top v^{(k)} = 0$ for all $k$.

I have some intuition that since $\lambda$ is real it implies that there should be some conditions for the arguments $\phi^{(k)}_i$. But, unfortunately, I cannot formulate it.